# Ordenes o pedidos Woocomerce en el dahsboard por usuario

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Saludos amigos de la comunidad, mi consulta es si hay un modo o script que muestre unicamente los pedidos del usuario de la sesión actual en la sección orders de woocommerce en el dashboard de wordpress o backend. Aclaro que no hablo de la página "intermedia" que habilita woocommerce por defecto, sino del Backend de wordpress, o instancia en la que se gestionan los plugins.

Mil gracias de antemano.

Comment: Sin duda lo hay, pero dudo que alguien responda, hacerlo no es dificil pero es laborioso, debes crear una pagina en wp en el backend, luego crear un query que traiga a los usuarios y los pedidos por usuario, si quieres algo amigable debes crear una interfaz, todo eso lleva tiempo, lo mejor es que busques algun plugin que haga el trabajo, sin codigo de por medio tu pregunta se basa en opiniones, por favor lee [ask]

Comment: Hola muchas gracias por tu respuesta, justamente es por lo que he buscado y lo obtenido es el único detalle que falta, no se descarta ninguna posibilidad y como el tuyo todos los aporte son bienvenidos, saludos.